# Can hair be cut on any day of the week?

Tags: belief, superstitions

Is there any special reason why elders recommend not to get hair cut on particular day like Tuesday?

Comment: superstition. not Hinduism.

Comment: Ok, and anything on not cutting hair on Tuesdays ?

Comment: Once hair is cut it's some part of body dead no body wants aducha on mangalavar which is auspicious day of the week